# Where do ASP.NET validation controls validate data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

According to Microsoft it is good enough to just use their validation controls to validate form data. The problem is, I'm not sure whether or not these controls also validate the information on the server as I see no code to indicate this. Client sided validation can easily be bypassed, so I'm wondering whether or not it would be useful for me to write my own validation class for server sided validation if the controls do not already do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you validate at Client Side first using [ASP.Net Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

When the page is posted back to server, you use [IsValid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate -

```
// If user disables java script, IsValid will return false.
if (IsValid)
{
    // Then you validate inputs based on your business logic.
}
```

Comment: If the user removes the client side Javascript validation, would IsValid still return true?

Comment: Answer is no. However, an experience user can manipulate the validation script; this is the reason you are validating again at server side. **The main reason using client side validation is you want to avoid unnecessary post back to server if *basic* validation is failed.**

Comment: The IsValid check is useless then, as like you said the validation code can be manipulated to return true no matter what. I assume Microsoft's validation controls do not in fact validate on the server, so I guess I'm going to have to write my own validation library.

Comment: The hope is that the vast majority of people will not in fact, tamper with javascript.  Yes there should be server side validation as well, and records shouldn't be inserted into your database without actually doing server side validation, however doing simple javascript checks will indeed reduce user error, and save round trips to and from the server.  To go so far as to call IsValid check "useless" is a pretty big leap, as it will be useful in the case of >99% of your users.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Microsoft's Server or Client Side validation tools. Its always best to validate your form before form submit. There are many many javascript libraries that can help you validate forms, including Parsley:

http://parsleyjs.org/

You can even do AJAX validations, so that you can lookup whether a value is valid in a database table.

Comment: You must always validate on the server, as you cannot trust that the client performed the validation correctly. That isn't to say client side validation can't be used too, but you need server side at a minimum.

Comment: I agree. Probably would do it the database level though, with constraints and the like.

Comment: AJAX would be useful, but relying on client side validation is asking for people to submit bogus data.